# what are the issues if any when installing Ubuntu only OS on a 2009 MacBook pro

Tags: mac, apple

I have recently purchased a MacBook pro cause I like the way it is built...but only want Ubuntu to run it. are there drivers and such to make it all work right?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any extra drivers. Only maybe nvidia, if there is an Nvidia adapter. But there may be some tricks with EFI, if you want to keep OSX.